# Problems with Staging .Rmd Markdown files on RStudio to Commit to Github

Tags: git, github, version-control, rstudio

I started a "New Project" in my local computer in RStudio with Version Control successfully. Then, I proceeded to modify a mardown (.Rmd) file that I had just received on the list of Files in my RStudio (the file was initially in my Github account). I knitted it to html and saved the .Rmd file in my local folder.

So far so good.

When I went to commit, I was able to select the .html file without a glitch, push it, and view it online. Perfect.

The problem is that I can't select the .Rmd file for "staging" (not sure I'm using the right term here), and subsequent "Push". So the changes I made in my local computer are not updated on Github. It is just impossible to get the selection box beside the .Rmd file on the "Commit" interface ("Review Changes") selected. Here's the screen shot with the name of the file blacked out:

[image]

Then I went the other way: changed the old .Rmd file directly on Github, and "Pull"-ed it down, getting the error that you can see below.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does the name of your R Markdown document, or any of its parent directories, contain a space?

Comment: Yes. The problem seems to be inconsistent - it doesn't happen all the time. But, yes, it does contain a space.

Comment: @Jonathan It stopped. Thank you!